# extract image url from html page with php

Tags: php, regex, image, url, html-parsing

how can I extract the post image from this link using php?

I read that I can't do it with regex.

http://www.huffingtonpost.it/2013/07/03/stupri-piazza-tahrir-durante-proteste-anti-morsi_n_3538921.html?utm_hp_ref=italy

Thank you so much.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: thanks, so how can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$content=file_get_contents($url);
if (preg_match("/<img.*src=\"(.*)\".*class=\".*pinit\".*>/", $content, $matches)) 
{
echo "Match was found <br />";
echo $matches[0];
}
```

$matches[0] will print the whole image tag.
And if you want to extract only the URL, then you can use $matches[1] to get the same :)

Comment: I'm trying to do the same for "http://techcrunch.com/2014/05/09/facebook-is-down-for-many/" but it doesn't return anything. I know the <img> lies here :<img src="http://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2014/05/screen-shot-2014-05-09-at-5-09-36-pm.png?w=738" class="" /> but even after few changes it doesn't return anything. Any help would be nice _/\_

Comment: That regex was very specific for the pattern in that particular web page.
Try this.

    if (preg_match("/<img.*src=\"(.*)\"/", $content, $matches)) 
    {
        echo "Match is found <br />";
        echo $matches[0];
    }

Working :  The regex will go in search for a src attribute within the image tag, then extracts the image URL that is assumed to be within double quotes.
You can modify it as of your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You can/must parse your html with DOM, here is example with your case:

```
$curlResource = curl_init('http://www.huffingtonpost.it/2013/07/03/stupri-piazza-tahrir-durante-proteste-anti-morsi_n_3538921.html?utm_hp_ref=italy');
curl_setopt($curlResource, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curlResource, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curlResource, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);

$page = curl_exec($curlResource);
curl_close($curlResource);


$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadHTML($page);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($domDocument);

$urlXpath = $xpath->query("//img[@id='img_caption_3538921']/@src");

$url = $urlXpath->item(0)->nodeValue;

echo $url;
```

Take your time and learn a little DOM and XPATH it's worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Try This ...

```
$content=file_get_contents($url);
if (preg_match("/src=[\"\'][^\'\']+[\"\']/", $content, $matches)) 
{
    echo "Match was found <br />";
    echo $matches[0];
}
```